# How to draw line between two points in a dataframe using matplotlib?

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib

I'm trying to compare my predicted output and the test data using matplotlib.As I'm new to python I'm not able to find how to connect each entry with line like in [this photo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VCSPZ.png).
I was able to write a code like this which compares the Y coordinate and entries but I'm unable to map each entry of test data with predicted output with a line

```
X_1 = range(len(Y_test))
plt.figure(figsize=(5,5))
plt.scatter(X_1, output, label='Y_output',alpha=0.3)
plt.scatter(X_1, Y_test, label='Y_test',alpha=0.3)
plt.title("Scatter Plot")
plt.legend()
plt.xlabel("entries")
plt.ylabel("Y value")
plt.show()
```

[graph we are getting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K18uI.png)

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this in addition to your code

```
plt.plot(np.stack((X_1,X_1)), np.stack((output,Y_test)), color="black")
```

In fact, to reproduce the plot you want, you need different x for `output` and for `Y_test` (for example, `X_1` and `X_2` that are different).